# What is actually the iPhone 6/7 screen width for CSS styles?

Tags: css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, browser

I read the iPhone 6/7 (S or not) has a browser width of 375px.

However, I am writing a simple @media query like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 375px) {
    ....
}
```

I found out that is not working until I increase the max-width to exactly 980px.
Why is that?

How can I make a @media query that treats the phone like it has 375px? I don't care how dense is the screen resolution, it is a small phone and I want to apply a phoney web design, without destroying the design for devices like tablets or small laptops with around 1000px resolution.

Ideally it should work with `col-xs-X` bootstrap's styles.

Comment: Did you open DevTools to see what could be possibly causing the issue? You should really be creating breaking points based on content, not on specific devices, products or brands.

Comment: Curiosity: Why are you using max-width, and not min-width?

Comment: What does your [meta viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) line say?

Comment: @ChrisYongchu, I was designing content-oriented, not device-oriented. However, when I tested it on my phone, I realised that the Bootstrap's styles being applied were the `col-sm-*` (min-width:768), instead of the `col-xs-*`. I used DevTools to find out these things.

Comment: @Alohci I did not have one. I read in your link that "If you’re coding your site using Responsive design in order to fit the iPhone well, you may have some sizing issues if you don’t tell the device not to zoom in." I added `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">` and now it is working fine. If you make it an answer I will accept it. Although, my initial question remains a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely another media query or default style overriding this.

Your media query is correct, but ALWAYS MAKE SURE that your media query is at the very end of your style.css file (Or whatever the name is).

Comment: but with max-width 980px IS being applied. So we are back to my main question. What is really the iPhone 6 browser width

Comment: Here is your answer: https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified